# Wieso wird aus "die Seite" plötzlich "der Seite" in folgendem Satz?

Tags: grammatical-case, article, wechselpraeposition

Ich bin gerade am Korrigieren eines deutschen Textes einer Freundin und meinte, dass es nicht "oben links auf die Loginseite" sondern "oben links auf der Loginseite" ist. Als Muttersprachler weiß ich zwar, dass "der" hier richtig ist aber kann die grammatische Regel dahinter nicht erklären.

Kann es sein, dass es was mit aktiv/passiv zu tun hat? Kann es mir sonst nicht wirklich erklären (zumindest mit den Regeln die ich damals gelernt hab und noch weiß, lol).

Comment: auf die Seite — Richtung // auf der Seite — Ort

Comment: @Janka sorry falls das nicht richtig rüberkam, mit Seite war eine website gemeint. Was mich dann verwirrt ist, dass man sagen kann "Die seite von google wird oft besucht" aber genauso "Auf der seite von google kann man buttons klicken"

Comment: @skkrrea Schau dir die Grammatik an, und da insbesondere die Deklination von Nomen. Die Verbform hat darauf keinen Einfluss (eher umgekehrt)

Comment: *Auf* ist eine Wechselpräposition, die mit Akkusativ steht, wenn eine Richtung gemeint ist, oder mit Dativ, wenn ein Ort gemeint ist.

Comment: Hallo. Sieh dich nach Subjekt und Objekt um und was es mit den Fällen auf sich hat. Da du in jedem Grammatiklehrbuch sofort fündig wirst, werden solche grundlegenden Fragen hier als off-topic angesehen. Sieh dir bitte auch die Tour an! Eigenrecherche wird hier vorausgesetzt.

Comment: Ein vollständiger Satz wäre hilfreich. "oben links auf die Login Seite" ist kein Satz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Auf" ist eine Präposition, und dazu gehört als Fall immer entweder ein Akkusativ ("Wen-Fall") oder ein Dativ ("Wem-Fall"):

> Sie sprang **auf die** Mauer *(Akkusativ)*.
> Sie saß **auf der** Mauer *(Dativ)*.

Der Akkusativ wird meistens benutzt, wenn es sich um eine Richtungsangabe handelt (Wohin? Auf wen oder was?) .

Der Dativ wird meistens benutzt, wenn es sich um eine Ortsangabe handelt (Wo? Auf wem oder was?).

> Beweg mal den Mauszeiger nach oben links **auf die** Login-Seite! *(Akkusativ, weil Richtung)*
> Siehst du das Icon oben links **auf der** Login-Seite? *(Dativ, weil Ortsangabe)*

Bei den Präpositionen *in*, *unter*, *über* und anderen   *Wechselpräpositionen* funktioniert es genauso:

> Ich gehe in die Stadt. *(Wohin?)*
> Ich bin in der Stadt. *(Wo?)*
> Er kroch unter die Decke.
> Er lag unter der Decke.
> Linas Fuß schwebte kurz über der Pfütze, bevor sie über sie hinweg sprang.

Answer (score 1):

Wie von HalvarF erläutert, kann die Präposition "auf" sowohl mit Akkusativ als auch mit Dativ verwendet werden.

Daher sind beide Formulierungen korrekt, müssen allerdings im Kontext gelesen werden.

1. Schau oben links auf **die** Loginseite.
   Hier wir der Akkusativ benutzt, weil eine Richtung angegeben wird.
2. Oben links auf **der** Loginseite befindet sich das Firmenlogo.
   Hier wir der Dativ benutzt, weil ein Ort angegeben wird.

Ich vermute zwar, dass der Frage ein Satz vom Typ 2 zugrundeliegt, aber ohne eine Information zum Kontext kann die Frage nicht eindeutig beantwortet werden.